# In Python, is there a way to automatically cast derived class operation results from an operator inherited from parent class to that derived class?

Tags: python, inheritance, casting, operator-overloading, operators

Suppose I made a custom class from a parent class that has all kinds of operators (`+`,`-`,`*`,`/`,etc) defined, and I want to keep how those operators work as-is. However, without overriding the operators, the returned values from them are of the parent class type. Is there a convenient way to automatically cast the operator results to my derived class type?

Here's an example -- `MySeries` is a class based on Pandas' `Series` class.

```py
import pandas as pd

class MySeries(pd.Series):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

if I make some instances from it, they'll be type `MySeries`, which is good.

```py
s1 = MySeries([1,2,3])
s2 = MySeries([4,5,6])

type(s1)
>>> __main__.MySeries
```

But when I do an operation like `+`, the returned value becomes the parent class:

```py
type(s1+s2)
>>> pandas.core.series.Series
```

My hope is `type(s1+s2)` can be of type `MySeries`. I know a dumb way to do it is to override e.g. the `__add__()` method:

```py
class MySeries(pd.Series):
    def __add__(self, other):
        return self.__class__(super().__add__(self, other))
```

but doing the same for all operators is quite tedious.

Is there a more elegant way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

This seems to do the trick:

```
class MySeries(pd.Series):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    @property
    def _constructor(self):
        return MySeries
```

To find this, I stepped through the addition arithmetic call with a debugger in order to find where the new value was created. It eventually called pd.Series._constructor for this.

Comment: Thanks, Dave! I tried this solution and it introduces another problem: the `_constructor` seems to be applied to unary operations like `MySeries.isna()` too. So suppose `MySeries` converts all values to `float` type in its `__init__()`, then `MySeries.isna()` would return a series of 0/1s instead of True/False. Hopefully `MySeries` is returned for some operations (like +-*/ and negation), but for `.isna()` a normal series of `True`/`False` would be more appropriate.

Comment: Maybe I'm not totally following your scenario, but this seems like an issue with having your constructor convert all values to floats. Can you use something like `from pandas.core.dtypes.missing import isna` in your constructor to prevent that?